# How to open a new window and inside displayed facebook page using iframe tag?

Tags: html, angular, iframe

i'm new for angular2, i have created angular2 application.

i have some problem for my angular2 app(sorry for my english language).. (**see the pictures**)
1.i displayed parent window, then parent window button click to open a new window, this is working fine.
2.But, i tried to displayed http://www.facebook page inside the new window using **iframe tag**. But, didn't fix it
 anyone can you help me!
**parent.component.html**

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="window.open()">click Me</a></div>
<iframe #window="child"></iframe>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
    selector: 'iframe',
    template: `<div>
    <h4>Angular2 app </h4>
     <iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="pdfUrl"></iframe>
    </div>`,
    exportAs: 'child',
})
export class IframeComponent {
    pdfUrl;
    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
  this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.facebook.co'); // how to dispaly the inside window?
    }

    open() {
        window.open('http://localhost:4200/SEA/mainpage','_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')     //this is working fine
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>`? (:

Comment: @ErhanYaşar, already used for <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>... , my problem is click a button on parent window, at time display new child window  and iframe tag using facebook window.

Comment: you may share some code sample that people can see easily what you did or didn't true/false. Your words are still not clear enough. If your purpose is to just opening a **new** `child window` then you just can type

**<a href="childwindow.html" target="_blank"></a>**

or please specify a bit more clearer explanation.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar i have edited my question(sorry for my bad english)